# iPad 2 charging very slow

Tags: battery, ipad, charging

My iPad 2 has recently become VERY slow to charge- about 1% every 10 minutes while plugged into my Retina MacBook Pro (my usual charging source). I've tried both USB ports on the rMBP and neither seems faster than the other. I checked the Apple support website and it was said to be a bug in iOS 7, but my iPad was charging fine for a few weeks after I updated.  What could be some possible causes of this.

NOTE: the battery drains at a normal rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB on a computer is not as punchy as a 10W Power adapter (2 Amps).

If you want a fast recharge, you should better use a power adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Put it into the Airplane mode and switch off the screen while charging. It will charge faster.